# magento 2.1.12 how to add custom attribute in address for rest api

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-attributes, customer-address

How to add custom attribute in address for rest api to set and get for view that attribute in magento 2.1.12 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Create a new column and set value for the existing order
Firstly, you need to create a new column in table sales_order and name for it set a value for the existing orders. In this post, we named it “**tip_and_trick_attribute**”.

**Step 2: Create a specific new Life**

Next, you create a file \app\code\Magento\TipandTrick\etc\extension_attributes.xml in the extension folder with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
    <attribute code="tip_and_trick_attribute" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

You have to create file extension_attributes.xml to add the custom attribute because Magento 2 doesn’t accept to add a new field in the response on the Rest API

**Step 3: Create observe**

In this step, you need to create observe for event ‘sales_order_load_after’ through the file \app\code\Magento\TipandTrick\etc\events.xml to add the custom attribute into extension_attributes.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_load_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_load_tip_and_trick_attribute" instance="Magestore\TipAndTrick\Observer\Sales\OrderLoadAfter" />
</event>
</config>
```

**Step 4: Create a file a handle the event**

Create a file app\code\Magento\TipandTrick\Observer\Sales\OrderLoadAfter.php to handle the event ‘sales_order_load_after’ which is declared above

```
<?php
namespace Magestore\TipAndTrick\Observer\Sales;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class OrderLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
        $extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();
    }
    $attr = $order->getData('tip_and_trick_attribute');
    $extensionAttributes->setTipAndTrickAttribute($attr);
    $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
}
private function getOrderExtensionDependency()
{
    $orderExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
        '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension'
    );
    return $orderExtension;
}
}
```

In execute a function, you get the custom attribute from order data and set it into extension attributes of the orders.

**Step 5: Delete folder to apply function**

Delete folder var\generation to apply function setTipandTrickAttribute’ and ‘getTipandTrickAttribute’ in file‘var\generation\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension.php’. This file will be auto-created.

After getting an order on Magento 2 Rest API, you can see the custom attribute in the response.

Thanks for reading!
for refrence:- **https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-get-value-of-custom-attribute-on-magento-2-rest-api/**